# pandas resample '3M' to JAN-MAR / APR-JUN /

Tags: python, pandas, resample

I have a pandas datable as (showing only 2 lines as example, sorted by DATE_1 after some processing)

|  | DATE_1 | DATE _ 2 | DIFF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1175 | 2010-01-01 | 2010-11-16 | 320 |
| 1170 | 2010-05-19 | 2010-11-06 | 171 |
| .... | ... | ... | ... |

so the first date is 2010-01-01.

I want to resample on a 3 months period and sum the DIFF values.
I do this by:
df[['DIFF']].resample('3M').sum()

what I get is a sum, 3 months after 3 months, as expected.
But the dates are not starting where I would expected/wanted them to.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-01-31 | 320 |
| 2010-04-30 | NaN |
| 2020-07-31 | 171 |

How can I make it so that the 3M matches JAN-MAR, APR-JUN, JUL-SEP, OCT-DIC?

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-03-31 | 320 |
| 2010-06-30 | 171 |
| 2010-09-30 | value.. |
| 2010-12-31 | value ... |
| 2011-03-31 | value ... |

ps: can't get the last table to format correctly (it does on the preview...)

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh for reformatting the post to make the last table show correctly

Comment: Not sure what happen, when I add line break at last table and save edits, the last *ps.* line gone, so I rollback to first version to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the left interval on M frequencies has the effect of intervals "going up" from first date of series:

```
df['diff'].resample('3M', closed='left').sum()

date1
2010-03-31    320
2010-06-30    171
```